# how to interpret the acquisiton on google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website that ran a contest for a month, with a subscription for a prize.

The number of people that registered for this contest was 132,041

Now today I check the stats on Google for the month that the contest was running, and I have that there are less visits than the number of people that registered. How can I explain this?

[image]

Comment: Monica, can you check the duplicity in registrations? Any chance there was a drop in GA measurement?

Without further information from your part, I am afraid the community here won't be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know your website but within one visit user can register couple accounts.

If you use stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js in google analytics then it ca be blocked by Adblock or they might be other tools can block analytics.

Comment: thank you! as I need to find any possible answeres for why the stats don't match with the unique number of visits

Comment: dc.js is not being blocked anymore, this was fixed and if a user is using any AdBlocking solution, there is a rollback to standard tracking (typically ga.js).

Comment: @PetrHavlík could you provide some source for that info? Anyway we need to worry about people who has old lists for Adblock and may still block our Google Analytics.

Comment: see this article: http://www.analyticsresults.com/2013/03/doubleclick-remarketing-and-adblock-our.html - comments. I can confirm this was announced in GACP forum, which unfortunately isn't public.